# Can we use Hadoop and any NoSQL database with Android instead of SQLite

Tags: android, mongodb, hadoop, nosql

Can anyone kindly tell that can we use Hadoop and any NoSQL database like MongoDB tec with Android instead of SQLite. And if yes then how to do that (I mean what is the process to do so), because SQLite is embedded in Android and for MongoDB etc will we have to use separate Server etc or it can be used as embedded.

And which DB is better to use SQLite or MongoDB

Comment: What's the rational behind running Hadoop/NoSQL on Andriod?

Comment: @Praveen Sripati: one of my friends told me to use Hadoop/NoSQL instead of SQLite, that why i was asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadoop itself is very resource intensive. It is developed for large cluster of machines not a single mobile device. Added to that the strength of NoSQLs is also the large cluster of machines that can process them. If you have such limited in storage and processor power machine as mobile device you will suffer a great overhead.

Maybe it will be possible to set Hadoop and NoSQL, but you will have to pay orders of magnitude in performance. I strongly suggest you do not do that - better start off learning traditional SQL.

Answer (score 1):

In cases, when relational databases will do, hadoop and NoSQL solutions are usually inferior solutions.
Usually scalability and fault tolerance are put in their DNA in expense of performance and efficiency. 
So I would not recommend trying these solutions in cases when your load / data volumes requires scale out to clusters.